# How can you minimise the time to copy development Hyper-V VM's?

Tags: hyper-v, snapshot

How can you minimise the time to copy development Hyper-V VM's?

I have a number of Hyper-V VM's which I want to regularly move between two machines ... one in work, the other at home

I can shut down the VM, copy the VHD's to an external drive, copy to the other machine, create a new VM and set it's drives to the VHD's ... but the VHD's are big, so it takes a long time to copy.

Same if I do the Export

I tried taking a snapshot, so the core VHD didn't change, only the AVHD, so minimising the file size that needs copying

But when I created the VM on the target machine, there wasn't any snapshot

*... I'm used to VMware Workstation where this process worked ...*

Comment: `Hyper-V Server` and `VMWare VCenter Server` exists for the purpose you describe.

Comment: When I wanted a portable VM when I used Virtual PC 2007, I just placed the virtual machine on the external storage, and moved the external storage.  This keeps you from copying files around.

Comment: @ramhound (a) is the performance of an external drive Ok?  (b) what about the actual configuration of the VM and the missing snapshots?

Comment: You have to copy over the base VHDD and the snapshots if you what Hyper-V to see them.  This basically means you have to copy over the entire directory and all files to make a machine portable.  Once Hyper-V knows about the VM, you just then replace the files, as needed.  As for the performance on an external flash drive, it was fine, the reason I was using it was for entirely different reasons though.  *I have transfered a Hyper-V VM before, the way I just explained though.*